# Foundation Accordion requires occasional reload of page; does not always open on click

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I've installed Foundation 5 using the `foundation-rails` gem.  I'm having a couple of strange behaviours with Accordion that I need to troubleshoot. (I have not changed anything from the default install.)

1. Accordion randomly fails to open.  When this happens, none of the accordions on the page will work, and even if you navigate to a different page, none of the accordions on that page will work.  However, if you reload the page with `ctl-r`, they all start working again.
2. Accordion fails to close windows when another one is clicked, as if `multi_expand: true` is set.
3. Clicking on the accordion toggles the content on/off but never closes other content.

I'm generating nested accordions. Sample of generated code:

```
<ul class='accordion' data-accordion>

    <!-- :partial => 'accordion' -->
    <li class="accordion-navigation">
        <a href="#panel563">§ 1910.1  Purpose and scope.</a>
        <div id="panel563" class="content">
            <div class="panel callout">
                <div><a href="/standard/563/letters">Letters of Interpretation (1)</a></div> 
                <p>§ 1910.1  Purpose and scope.</p>
            </div>
            <div>
<!-- begin recursion -->
                <ul class='accordion' data-accordion>

                    <!-- :partial => 'accordion' -->
                    <li class="accordion-navigation">
                        <a href="#panel564">§ 1910.1(a) Section 6(a) of the Williams-Steiger Occupational Safety and...</a>
                        <div id="panel564" class="content">
                            <div class="panel callout">

                                <p>Section 6(a) of the Williams-Steiger Occupational Safety and Health Act of 1970 (84 Stat. 1593) provides that “without regard to chapter 5 of title 5, United States Code, or to the other subsections of this section, the Secretary shall, as soon as practicable during the period beginning with the effective date of this Act and ending 2 years after such date, by rule promulgate as an occupational safety or health standard any national concensus standard, and any established Federal standard, unless he determines that the promulgation of such a standard would not result in improved safety or health for specifically designated employees.” The legislative purpose of this provision is to establish, as rapidly as possible and without regard to the rule-making provisions of the Administrative Procedure Act, standards with which industries are generally familiar, and on whose adoption interested and affected persons have already had an opportunity to express their views. Such standards are either (1) national concensus standards on whose adoption affected persons have reached substantial agreement, or (2) Federal standards already established by Federal statutes or regulations.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
    <!-- begin recursion -->

    <!-- end recursion -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end partial -->


                </ul>
                <ul class='accordion' data-accordion>

                    <!-- :partial => 'accordion' -->
                    <li class="accordion-navigation">
                        <a href="#panel565">§ 1910.1(b) This part carries out the directive to the Secretary of Labor...</a>
                        <div id="panel565" class="content">
                            <div class="panel callout">

                                <p>This part carries out the directive to the Secretary of Labor under section 6(a) of the Act. It contains occupational safety and health standards which have been found to be national consensus standards or established Federal standards.</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
    <!-- begin recursion -->

    <!-- end recursion -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- end partial -->

                </ul>

<!-- end recursion -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end partial -->


</ul>
```

Comment: This might be better purposed as a submission of a bug to Foundation proper.

Comment: I gave up on accordion and went with a simple JQuery function to do the same thing; but I had problems with JQuery being dependent on reloading the page also.  The problem came from turbolinks.  I replaced the default installation of turbolinks with gem 'jquery-turbolinks' and my javascript now works fine.  Probably was the problem with accordion, too.